# C# Using regex, how to find a language in url

Tags: c#, regex

I have a class library to add a customized toolbox to a external IE browser.
I'm using SHDocVw to do the back/forward buttons (e. g.). My question is, sense this is multilingual, how can I change the buttons text...
The url give me "/en/" or "/ar/", how can i catch this?
Thanks

With the Mati Cicero answer I managed to do it.

string page = ie.LocationURL;
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"https?://[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]+(/((?'lang'ar|en)|.*))/?");

var lang = rgx.Match(page).Success ? rgx.Match(page).Groups[1].Value : "ar";

Comment: You can't. Not unless there is a predictable format for the rest of the URL but, based on your question, I assume there isn't (because otherwise you would have mentioned it).

Comment: I can retrive the url (as a string). I never done regex, so i'm asking for help.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question without knowing the URL format (and whether it is standard). Regex can't magically detect language codes.

Comment: Can you suggest another way.

Comment: Without more information on the structure of the URLs? No.

Comment: The url have this structure:
http://www.sitename.com/en/pages/default.aspx

Comment: I'd suggest looking into proper .net internationalization techniques instead of trying to hack together a solution based on URL matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following regex, I tried to make it as much generic as I could:

```
https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+(\/((?'lang'es|en)|.*))\/?
```

You would then examine the group **"lang"** to see if a match was made.

You would aso like to add more available languages (Added ***ch*** and ***in***):

```
https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-_]+(\/((?'lang'es|en|ch|in)|.*))\/?
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try

Comment: If you already know all of the language codes then using regex is a little redundant, don't you think?

Comment: You know the language codes, but you don't know which one requested the client

Answer (score 1):

If its always the first directory;

```
var lang = new Uri("http://sitename.com/en/pages/default.aspx")
               .Segments[1].Replace("/", string.Empty).ToLower();
```